# Hiding the text in an element with JS (not the element itself)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to hide the *text* in a HTML element, and not the element itself, using JavaScript? So if one had

```
<span style="border: 1px solid green">Hello world!</span>
```

how could one hide the "Hello world!" but not the border? If there is also a simplified jQuery solution, can you include it too?

Comment: adding `color: transparent;` or `visibility: hidden;` to the style won't work?

Comment: Define “hiding”. Should it be invisible but still occupy the space? Or should the page appear as if the text were not there? Should it be hidden from screen readers, search engines, etc.? Should it appear as normal text when CSS is disabled? Explaining the purpose of “hiding” might help in addressing the right problem.

Comment: Hiding as in adding a display:none style to the text, but not to the element itself. Sorry for the misunderstanding :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. it's called `.wrapInner()`.

```
$("div").wrapInner('<span class="hide" />');
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9KzgJ/

Comment: Is that a JS pre-defined method or is it a jQuery-defined one?

Comment: It's clearly a jQuery function. See how @ahren uses $('div') and not just document.getElementById()

Answer (score 1):

`$(<mydiv>).css('color', $(<mydiv>).css('background-color'))` is the only solution which does not change the DOM.

If you accept to change, you can use something like `$(<mydiv>).html($('<div>'+$(<mydiv>).html())+'</div>').css({visibility: 'hidden'}))`

Or something like that.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a block-level element, you can use `text-indent:-9999px;`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a nested span and hide it...

```
<span style="border: 1px solid green"><span id="text1">Hello world!</span></span>
```

Comment: Yes, hide using `visibility: hidden` (using `display: none` on the inner element contained in an inline element like a span will cause the parent to collapse to zero width.

Comment: No, but I mean without using another element.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no.

Sadly, without replacing the element all together, hiding the element, or changing the element text to be blank there is no way to just hide the text...

However, you could use javascript to append an identical element.. then hide the element you want...

But aside from that option, Gordon Bell's answer is probably your best option...